# Meaning of 'affine' in affine connection

Tags: differential-geometry

Is the 'affine' in affine connection what allows me to write
$$
\nabla_v = v^{\mu}\nabla_{\mu}
$$
where $v$ is a vector field and $\mu$ index in some basis? I mean is it connected to the fact that the induced covariant differential $\nabla_v$ is linear in its argument (the argument being a vector field)?

This might be my mistake, but I would expect that I can define a parallel transport rather arbitrarily, but when I define it using the affine connection, its has the above expressed property w.r.t. the vector fields.

I tried to find the answer here and on wiki but if it is there I do not see it. Please note that I come from relativistic physics background, not mathematical, if that should help you formulate the answer.

Comment: According to the introduction of the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_connection) (second paragraph), *The terminology is due to Cartan and has its origins in the identification of tangent spaces in Euclidean space $\Bbb R^n$ by translation: the idea is that a choice of affine connection makes a manifold look infinitesimally like Euclidean space not just smoothly, but as an affine space.*

Comment: I would add that the definition of a connection is also affine in the sense that it does not require a metric.